# Is there a way to make my background iPhone app to go foreground?

Tags: iphone, background, multitasking, foreground

Is there a way to make my background iPhone app to go foreground?

Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

A **`UILocalNotification`** will bring the app to the foreground if the **device is locked**, a **notification appears**, and the **user unlocks** the device.

A **`UILocalNotification`** with an **alertAction** will display the alert while the **device is unlocked**, and if the **user taps the View button** (or whatever you set it to), your app will be brought to the front.

Answer (score 1):

Not for your app, but the user could do it.
You could schedule a UILocalNotification to inform the user that you are done with your task or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. But you can do something when you feel must do. For example, use remote Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) to notify your user that you want her to bring your app back to the foreground.

Or, as JustSid put it, use local notification to notify your user that you want her attention.